# Larger text edit box for .cshtml file than a prompt()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

In my .cshtml I have the following code:

```
 (as part of <div id="buttons")
  <button id="Route" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="rRoute()">Draw Route</button>


  function rRoute() {        
            var route = prompt("Please paste in the route.");
            if (route != null && route != "") {
                alert("route is not implemented yet.");
            }
        }
```

The prompt only gives a single line, is there something that I can use to get a bigger box that will take multiple lines (approx 15 lines), (that I could then read into a string list/array). I have seen posts on TextArea using @Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows = 10, cols = 40})
but how to I incorporate something this into my .cshtml file, or is there a better option? I still want it to be a pop up on the page not a new page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a modal,and put TextArea into it.Here is a demo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Draw Route
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Please paste in the route.</label>
                @Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows = 15, cols = 40 })
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the above instead of the @Html I used

```
<textarea id="naipsData" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

as the layout looked a lot nicer to me. but couldn't have done it without help from Yiyi You getting the modal part right.